# Upgrade existing MongoDB 3.0.7 cluster to MongoDB 3.2.0 cluster

Tags: mongodb-3.0

MongoDB 3.2 uses wiredTiger as the default storage engine, I have upgraded 3.0.7 cluster to 3.2 without touching the config files, everything works fine, but I need to convert config servers to replica set, how do I preserve the current data on config servers that are running old storage engine?

Comment: Do you have different config servers for upgraded cluster of 3.2 version or the same config servers??? I just want to understand as it was not mentioned in the question.

Comment: Config severs storage engine can be different from the cluster. Refer this link https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/release-notes/3.0-upgrade/ though it is upgrade document from 2.6-3.0, I think the procedure might remain same.

Comment: I use the same 3 servers and going to add two more, I convert it to replica set.
@harshavmb the procedure can't be the same, config servers can work as a replica set now.

Comment: Okies..  Can you pass the link about the change in usage of replica sets.  Thanks

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/sharded-cluster-config-servers/

https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/sharded-cluster-high-availability/#sharding-config-servers-and-availability

choose v3.2